# Where is the AppAssertionCredentials for Go?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-bigquery

I am trying to build an App Engine application that will push data to BigQuery. However, the examples for authenticating in Java/Python reference AppAssertionCredentials, which I can't find in the Go libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [serviceaccount.go](https://code.google.com/p/goauth2/source/browse/appengine/serviceaccount/serviceaccount.go) from the goauth2 package.